# Episerver – Why is property setter bypassed?

Tags: episerver

It seems that content model setter is called only once when created from within

```
SetDefaultValues(ContentType contentType)
```

**I performed some tests:**

**1. Create new block**

1. Properties are tried to be set with some values from `SetDefaultValues`.
2. Because of setters implementation other values are used.

```cs
[ContentType(DisplayName = "SetterTestsBlock", GUID = "43ca7e93-6982-4b95-b073-c42af6ad2315", Description = "")]
public class SetterTestsBlock : BlockData
{
  public virtual string SomeVirtualStringProperty
  {
    get => this.GetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeVirtualStringProperty);
    set { this.SetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeVirtualStringProperty, "Ahoj1"); }      
  }

  public string SomeStringProperty
  {
    get => this.GetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeStringProperty);
    set { this.SetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeStringProperty, "Ahoj2"); }    
  }

  public override void SetDefaultValues(ContentType contentType)
  {
    SomeVirtualStringProperty = "Čau1";
    SomeStringProperty = "Čau2";
  }
}
```

**The result is expectable**

[image]

**2. Create new block again**

1. Let setters throws exception.

```cs
[ContentType(DisplayName = "SetterTestsBlock", GUID = "43ca7e93-6982-4b95-b073-c42af6ad2315", Description = "")]
public class SetterTestsBlock : BlockData
{
  public virtual string SomeVirtualStringProperty
  {
    get => this.GetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeVirtualStringProperty);
    //set { this.SetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeVirtualStringProperty, "Ahoj1"); }
    //set { }
    set { throw new Exception(); }
  }

  public string SomeStringProperty
  {
    get => this.GetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeStringProperty);
    //set { this.SetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeStringProperty, "Ahoj2"); }
    //set { }
    set { throw new Exception(); }
  }

  //public override void SetDefaultValues(ContentType contentType)
  //{
  //    SomeVirtualStringProperty = "Čau1";
  //    SomeStringProperty = "Čau2";
  //}
}
```

**This time the result is also quite expectable**

1. No default values override call = no default values, resp. no exception.

[image]

**3. Publish changes to block from test 2**

1. Input some values in CMS web interface.
2. Publish changes.

[image]

This result **is not** so expectable

1. CMS shows no errors so no exception was thrown.

[image]

### Summary

1. Property setter is called only from `SetDefaultValues(ContentType contentType)` method (during block first-time creation).
2. Observed behaviour does not depend on property virtuality (`virtual` modifier).

**The Problem**

Imagine situation illustrated by code underneath.

```cs
[ContentType(DisplayName = "RealUsageSimulation", GUID = "12737925-ab51-4f63-9144-cd4632244a1c", Description = "")]
public class RealUsageSimulation : BlockData
{
  public string SomeStrPropWithDependency
  {
    get => this.GetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeStrPropWithDependency);
    set
    {
      this.SetPropertyValue(t => t.SomeStrPropWithDependency, GetDbStoreFormValue());
        
      string GetDbStoreFormValue()
      {  
         return string.Join(
           ",",
           value
             .Split(new[] { '♦', '♣', '♠'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(x => x.Trim()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since issue described in **summary** setter logic is basically useless.

Am I wrong in some part?

I know how to solve this problem other proper way. **I just wonder why setter is not called.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property values aren't saved through the model class' property when, for example, saving content by editing it in edit mode (remember: content can be saved even if the content type *class* is removed from code).

The reason why the setter is called in `SetDefaultValues` is because *your* code uses the class property.

For your case, it would perhaps be more suitable to wire up the `ContentSaving` event to make any property value changes when content is being saved.

Comment: Ah, you right. I’d not realized content model does exists on DB level until it is manually removed. The IConentEvents I know.